# Sort RDD based on a value in a tuple in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

Let's say I have an RDD of 3 rows as follows

```
{(Sam, 23), 1}
{(Ram, 32), 5}
{(Dan, 25), 2}
```

The first column is a tuple of say, (name, age). In Scala, how to sort this RDD based on only the name field in first column? Similarly how to sort this RDD based on age?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sortBy`

```
val rdd : RDD[((String,Int),Int)] = ???

rdd.sortBy{case ((name,age),_) => name}
```

Sort by age:

```
rdd.sortBy{case ((name,age),_) => age}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sparkContext.parallelize(Array( ("Sam", 23),("Ram", 32),("Dan", 25) )).sortBy(_._1)//If it's inverted order,input false ,If you pass the age _1 to _2
.foreach(println)`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuDXK.png)